# jQuery mouseover effect

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm sure it is something simple I am missing out but I can't get this jQuery function to work. No errors are coming up in the console either. I want text to appear when a user hovers over the image. Any chance someone can spot what I am doing wrong?

HTML

```
 <div class="project-container">
     <img src="imgs/portfolio_hiburn.jpg">
          <div class="project-container__text">
              <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat..
              </p> 
          </div>
 </div>
```

CSS

```css
.project-container {
    width: 38.4688rem;
    height: 28.9rem;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.project-container__text {
    padding: 2rem;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    display: none;
    background: #63b9ce; 
    color: #fff;
}

.project-display {
    display: inline;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.project-container').mouseover(function(){
        $('.project-container__text').addClass(('.project-display'), function(){
            $('.project-display').slideUp();
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Well that issue is fixed, and I stupidly was using the slideUp thinking it would animte but I found out it removes the element with that effect. I've installed the jQuery-UI CDN, and am wanting to use the slide effect it has to offer. Again no errors but it is abruptly appearing rather than sliding it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the `(` and a `.` from the adding class:

```
.addClass('project-display'),
```

You have added an extra `(` brace in `addClass()` method and this method does not accept any selector but a string value. So you don't have to put a `.` there.

and one thing to be added you have to get the element in the given context of the selector with `this` keyword:

```
$(this).find('.project-container__text').addClass('project-display')
```

Comment: Another quesiton, my effects aren't taking the speed argument. Any ideas why?

Comment: _speed argument_ in slideup you meant to say or anywhere else?

Comment: The slide up effect isn't working. The text slides up but then disappears.

Comment: That is what slideup method does. it slide up and hides the element.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go! 
The problem was you shouldnt add '.' when using addClass or removeClass function. Also would recommend using .on('mouseover') with callback.

https://jsbin.com/wowuyuzaqo/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.project-container').mouseover(function(){
        $('.project-container__text', this)
            .addClass('project-display')
            .slideUp();
    });
});
```

Comment: The slide up effect isn't working. The text slides up but then disappears.

Answer (score 0):

You must change the way CSS class assignment:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.project-container').mouseover(function(){
        $('.project-container__text').addClass('project-display');
        $('.project-display').slideUp();
    });
});
```

[This is your code running in fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tgxqhubs/)

***You should consider that to apply a style class to a jquery item, you must have the following format***

> More than one class may be added at a time, separated by a space, to
>   the set of matched elements, like so: `$( "p" ).addClass( "myClass  yourClass" );`
>
> This method is often used with .removeClass() to switch elements'
>   classes from one to another, like so: `$( "p" ).removeClass( "myClass noClass" ).addClass( "yourClass" );`
>
> Here, the myClass and noClass classes are removed from all paragraphs,
>   while yourClass is added. As of jQuery 1.4, the .addClass() method's
>   argument can receive a function.
>
> ```
> $( "ul li" ).addClass(function( index ) {
>   return "item-" + index;
> });
> ```
>
> Given an unordered list with two `<li>` elements, this example adds the
>   class "item-0" to the first `<li>` and "item-1" to the second.
>
> **Reference: [addClass Jquery Doumentation](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/)**